# How to change the size of a ProgessBar / Slider?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

i try to create a user interface with LibGDX with table layouts but couldnt find a solution how to set the size / resize ProgressBars or Sliders.

Buttons are already sized as big as their parent table cell, for the image of CheckBoxes i found the workaround with:

```
checkBox.getCells().get(0).size(sizeX, sizeY);
```

But for ProgressBars i couldnt find any solution yet.
I dont want to stretch the whole screen with a different viewport and all the setScale(), setWidth.. of the widget are not rescaling the image.

Is there any possibility other than creating different images for different resolutions or am i on a completely wrong way?

Thanks for every help. :)

Comment: What about `ProgressBar.setSize()`?

Comment: Its the same as with setWidth(), it does nothing. Atleast i cant recognize any difference, the background-image doesnt scale.

Answer (score 3):

```
 volumeSlider.getStyle().knob.setMinHeight(100)
```

Edit:

The knob is the button to pinch with scrolling. It is stored in the style of a Slider. So you get it that way `volumeSlider.getStyle().knob`.

As everything is declared before the real packing and surface extention, the most robust ay is to set it's min height.

Comment: A couple of words to summarize the main aspect of your proposal ?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to extend the [Slider](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Slider.java) class and **override the method `getPrefWidth`** from class ProgressBar. I came to this solution by looking at the source code of the [ProgressBar](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ProgressBar.java), where you can see, that the width of a horizontal slider is set to 140.